# Use watch to copy new files in directory twice a second

Tags: unix, watch, cp

I have a folder (foo) that I want check twice a second. If there is any new file in that folder I want to copy it to a second folder (foo2). I want to use watch and cp. I am using tcsh.

How to do this?

This is what I am trying:

```
touch lastChanged
watch --interval=.5 'if [[ $(ls foo) ]] then cp $; else echo "nothing new";fi
```

Comment: FWIW - if you have the inotify command you might want to use that instead.  You can tell it to notify you when ever a file is created (bad idea for what you are doing), written, opened, etc.  You want files that were just closed right now to cp the entire file.  I suggested this because you appear to be on linux - the watch command is part of most linux distributions.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Unfortunately I do not have it and do not have access to get it.

Comment: I do not know csh or tcsh, so I cannot help there.  However, running something every 500ms that is doing an "ls" and then additional processing is going to use up resources, and you have no guarantee that the file you just copied has been completely written and closed, AFAIK.  When you cp a file you only get the content currently written to it.  I do not know if this is an issue for you.  If I understand correctly, you are probably copying files repeatedly as they grow.  cp is not smart and cp's the whole file.

Comment: I just need it to run for a little <= 2 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me. I am open to better answers.

```
touch lastChecked
watch --interval=.5 'if [[ $(find foo -newer lastChecked -ls -exec cp {} foo2 \; then touch lastChecked; else echo "nothing new"; fi
```

Watch checks twice a second.

Find looks for files that are newer than the "lastChecked" file and copies those files.

Then touch lastChecked.

Touching lastChecked also will allow for cping when a file has been updated.